# Different reactions from diffrent projects on same machine for calling same API -> SSLException

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat

I have a single page web application(Spring MCV + JSF(primefaces) + tomca 8) that runs on a `Development-server` , it makes API call for getting data from providers (for example https://stream.xyz.com),
at first I had **SSLHandshakeException** :

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

After some research, I found out that what the problem is and I resolved it by exporting the domain certificate and manually added it into `/jdk/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/security/cacerts` by some commands, and then my issue resolved.

***But the main problem:***

I have a SpringBoot(v 1.5.12) application that `on production-server it has SSL enabled, I mean that in /resources folder I have a SSLKeystore.p12` that contains my certificate but when I run it `on development-server(which mentioned webApp exists) SSL configs have been commented` and it again wants to make an API call to the same domain and here I am facing the `SSLHandshakeException` as mentioned above.

Does springBoot not using the `cacerts` file that I added the domains cert in it?

Any idea about how to resolve this issue will be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

After some researchs I have added this configuration class in project:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:SSLConfigs.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
public class SSLConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureSSL() {
        //set to TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1");

        //load the 'javax.net.ssl.trustStore' and
        //'javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword' from application.properties
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", env.getProperty("server.ssl.trust-store"));
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",env.getProperty("server.ssl.trust-store-password"));
    }
}
```

and also these in property file:

```
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:classpath:SSLKeystore.p12
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
```

and now I am facing this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
> parameter must be non-empty
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:90)
> at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
> at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
> at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
> ... 144 more Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
> parameter must be non-empty
> at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
> at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.(PKIXParameters.java:120)
> at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:88)